# How to set different lifetime managers in Prism 7 with Unity container

Tags: wpf, unity-container, prism, prism-7

In older versions of Prism I was able to do this from UnityBootstrapper class

```
    protected override void ConfigureContainer()
    {
        base.ConfigureContainer();
        Container.RegisterType<IViewDragService, ViewDragService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
    }
```

What would be equivalent of this code for Prism 7 when unity container is used ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `GetContainer` on the container abstraction you receive from prism to get the actual `IUnityContainer`:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().RegisterType<IViewDragService, ViewDragService>(new HierarchicalLifetimeManager());
```